# Horizontal mouse wheel event? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Some laptops have a trackpad that can do horizontal scrolling as well as vertical (WM_MOUSEWHEEL), and some desktop mice have ability to tilt their wheels.

How can I handle horizontal scrolling from a trackpad or mouse wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WM_MOUSEHWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645614(VS.85).aspx) is sent to the active window when the mouse's horizontal scroll wheel is tilted or rotated, and is also useful for horizontal scrolling from a trackpad's horizontal scrolling control